# Navigation action using date parameters in Quicksight

Tags: navigation, parameter-passing, action, amazon-quicksight

I have a chat bar with year in X and Month in group like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgSUQ.png)

When I click on the month bar, I have a navigation action passing the Month and Year to another worksheet where I have a data table. I need to filter this data table using the parameters, but in this table I have the actual quantity of the month, the quantity of the previous month and the quantity of the same month of the previous year. When I filter the month, the previous month calculation doesn’t work because the action is filtering only the actual month.

This way I can't calculate the quantity of the previous month and the quantity of the same month of the previous year. Only the actual quantity works.

I must click on the bar chart and pass this data to another spreadsheet as a parameter. This way, I would have a table showing only the filtered month and year data and all the KPIs working: quantity of the filtered month, quantity of the filtered previous month and quantity of the filtered month of the previous year.